# Spark read multi-line records with slidingRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to process a file with spark but my input file has a single "record" of information spread over 3 lines.

```
Rec1 Line1
Rec1 Line2
Rec1 Line3
Rec2 Line1
Rec2 Line2
Rec2 Line3
```

There is no key linking the lines of a record, the only connection is that they are three lines next to each other.  There is no record separator beyond the knowing that the 4th line is the start of a new record.  All other questions I saw related to multi-line records seem to have some sort of obvious record separator while I have none in this case, I have to rely on line count.

My first thought is to use the `sliding` function from `org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions`

```
sc.textFile("myFile.txt").sliding(3,3)
```

This turns my RDD[String] into and RDD[Array[String]] where each element in the RDD is 3 lines from the file.

In some tests this looks like it works are gets me the result I want, however I notice that the `sliding` function actually causes a `collect` during its evaluation.  This has me concerned, what is it collecting?  Is it the entire data file or something else?  My file will be too large to collect the entire thing onto the driver.

Is `sliding` the best way to read this file, or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Can't you use rdd.map(_.split(" ")).map(arr => (arr[0], arr[1])).groupBy(_._2) ? That means split your line by space, make a rdd of key, value and group by key.

Comment: @dumitru There is no key in the file to groupBy.  I could maybe use `zipWithIndex` to get keys to use for grouping.  This also causes a full shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

The `collect()` call you're seeing doesn't collect all the RDD data, but rather partition summary information.  Calling `.sliding` will cause your text file to be read an extra time to compute this information, but it won't cause you to blow out your driver memory.

I learned this from reading the code in `org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.SlidingRDD` in Spark 2.0.2.

For your purpose, `.sliding` seems to be the best bet.